# What are the wireless display options for MacBook Air?

Tags: mac, wifi, display

Are there any viable Wireless display solutions for MacBook Air (with Thunderbolt port). I know I can connect to HDMI-compatible TV or Monitor using cables and convertors. Is there any way I can avoid using wires?

First thing that comes to my mind is [DLNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) since so many TVs support DLNA. But that is just for streaming videos and not for normal laptop usage. I am curious to know any solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not available until this summer, the next version of the Mac OS (Mountain Lion) will allow you use [AirPlay on some Macs to send your display to an AppleTV](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#airplay).

From the site:

> **Your Mac is on TV.** This new feature in Mountain Lion is made for an audience. With AirPlay Mirroring, you can stream what’s on your Mac to your HDTV via Apple TV. Show web pages and videos to friends on the couch. Share lessons with a classroom. Present to a conference room. It’s a big deal for your Mac. And for everyone around it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Nyrius Wireless AV Sender](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005H3AU1Y). If you're looking for a small, slick unit to get your presentations displayed while visiting clients it probably isn't for you. If you want to get content from your Macbook Air onto your wall-mounted display at home without stringing a long HDMI cable across the room it might be just what you want.

An alternative - look at this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgGGIxUqQs0) showing how to do it with an intermediate iPad, maybe not so practical. It uses an app called [iDisplay for $4.99](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/idisplay/id363500805?mt=8). In that it seems to be doing the same kind of function as [Air Display](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/air-display/id368158927?mt=8) which I use and would recommend over anything else.

Second alternative - [AirFlick from Erica Sadun](http://ericasadun.com/) - allows you to make your Mac an AirPlay source so you can mirror its display to an AppleTV, just as if it was an iPad. This won't be as easy as we might expect of Mac software, Erica is an awesome hacker but doesn't employ a team of graphic and web designers to make beautiful lick able software.

Comment: I did come across Nyrius on my search, but it is still a compromise for my need because I need to connect my mac to the sender box, so instead of being bound to the TV I am bound to another box few feet away. What I am looking for is a way to use Wireless Adapter (or any other Wireless component if any available on my MBA) to connect to the TV. In that way I am completely mobile inside my Home. Sounds far fetched?

Comment: OK, a couple of alternatives added which I think you will like.

Comment: OK AirFlick with AppleTV is the closest solution, but it is still fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MECast dongle will do the job and only costs around $35 online! It is much better than Chromecast for the price.

It supports mirroring Windows PC Laptops as well as MacBook in addition to Android phone and tablet in Miracast functions including Audio. It is also compatible with iPhone/iPad too! It supports DLNA and Airplay as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am running windows 8.1 on a macbook air 2012 and the screen mirroring is working flawlessly (1920 X1080). The TV connects as a projector under devices and you can either duplicate, extend or display on tv only. If you really want the screen mirroring function you should install windows 8.1 which supports this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

An airplay device is not always required. We have created solutions that mirror your mac screen for a number of TV brands:

Mirror for Samsung TV: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1107644799?at=11l9Aw&mt=12

Mirror for LG TV: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1152966194?at=11l9Aw&mt=12

A similar solution is also available for Panasonic TV's

These apps use DLNA to stream your screeen directly to your TV

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome to cast your mac to android tv(Or any device which supports chrome cast).[image: Check attached image to know how to do it.]

Answer (score 0):

There's an app that will allow you to cast from roku to mac.[Airplay works on Roku](https://support.roku.com/article/360057488733)